# How Can I make check box required true inside a datatable when a command button clicked outside the datable but inside the form?

Tags: jsf-2, checkbox, jboss7.x

I have multiple forms each has at least a command button rendered based different conditions.I have a datatable inside a form in which one column is `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`. And outside of that datatable I placed a command button so user can select a row by selecting the checkbox and submit the form. I am able to perform this task successfully.

But I have to make  `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` required when only the commandbutton inside this particular form is clicked. But when I do the following way it's not working at all. How can I make checkbox required when user doesn't select any checkbox inside the datatable and submits the form?

```
    < h:form prependId="false" rendered="#{bean.somecondition}">

                    <h:dataTable id="userdata" value="#{bean.list}" var="obj">

                         <h:column>
                                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox required="#{not empty param[commandbutton.clientId]}"
                                                                    requiredMessage="Please select atleast one check box to proceed."
                                                                    value="#{bean.checked[obj.Id]}" />
                       </h:column>

                    </h:dataTable>

                  <h:commandButton value="submit" binding="#{commandbutton}"
                        action="#{bean.someaction}">
                </h:commandButton>

    </h:form>
```

I am able to make it work with Javascript

```
           $(function(){
            $('#formId').submit(function(e){
                      var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
                     if(!checkboxes.is(":checked")){
                         $('#listcheck').show();   // This is a div contained the validation message.
                          e.preventDefault();
                         }
                     })
               });
```

But I want to do it with JSF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `required="true"` doesn't work on checkboxes in first place. This is completely regardless of whether it's inside a data table or not and also whether the `required` attribute is hardcoded with `true` or coming from an EL expression.

Concrete cause is that the checked value is **never** `null`. When it's unchecked, it's simply `false`, not `null` or empty string. Therefore the `required="true"` validation always passes, even when unchecked.

The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has already identified this problem and offers an [`omnifaces.RequiredCheckboxValidator`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/RequiredCheckboxValidator) for the very purpose.

In your particular case, you could use it as follows:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox 
    requiredMessage="Please select at least one check box to proceed."
    value="#{bean.checked[obj.Id]}">
    <f:validator 
        validatorId="omnifaces.RequiredCheckboxValidator" 
        disabled="#{empty param[commandbutton.clientId]}" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Comment: @BalusC......... Thanks for explanation. I completely missed the part `the checked value is never null` when I was thinking about it. Anyways we are already using `omnifaces` in our application. I will implement this code in our application.